# how to add System.Windows.Controls.Frame to my reference in my project

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

The following code runs on SL4.. this works:

`((System.Windows.Controls.Frame)(this.Parent)).Navigate(new Uri("/Import",UriKind.Relative));`

but I want to add the reference `System.Windows.Controls.Frame`
to my project and I cannot find it. why is that?

(I right click on my proj  > Add Reference...  on .NET tab)

Answer (score 1):

There is no `System.Windows.Controls.Frame` assembly... The [`Frame`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class is in the `System.Windows.Controls.Navigation` assembly

Comment: Vs 2010 object browser searching for Navigate shows 
System.Windows.Controls.Frame

Comment: It's the full type name (namespace + name), not the assembly